# Issue with negative value when using NETWORKDAYS

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have created the formula

```
=-1+NETWORKDAYS(I18;J18;Helgdagar!A8:A35)
```

to calculate the difference between two dates. Standard Excel behaviour is that if it is the same date in both columns, it shows the value `1` but I want to display the value `0` instead (hence the `-1+` in the beginning).

So far so good. The problem I have with this formula is if the date in J-column comes before the date in I-column. Let's say that it says April 8th in the J-column and April 10th in the I-column. Then it should say -2 but instead it says -3. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
=-1+IF(J18<I18,NETWORKDAYS(J18;I18;Helgdagar!A8:A35),NETWORKDAYS(I18;J18;Helgdagar!A8:A35))
```

Put an if statement in to compare which is the smaller value and then use the appropriate formula that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a way I have used:-

```
=NETWORKDAYS(I18;J18;Helgdagar!A8:A35)-sign(NETWORKDAYS(I18;J18;Helgdagar!A8:A35))
```

So it subtracts 1 if the NETWORKDAYS result is positive (including the case when both dates are the same) and adds one if it is negative.